# MySQL docker container query return null to just inserted value

Tags: javascript, mysql, webrtc

I've created a web-app using two containers: tomcat, hosting web-app, and mysql (from official mysql image) for db. Well, i have to insert into db a specific attribute of WebRTC SDP (a=fingerprint line);

[Here](https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/) There is an example of WebRTC SDP: i've parsed it and recovered the "a=fingerprint" line.

I've parsed it, with this javascript function, in which I've deleted the initial "a=fingerprint:" string of the line and the trailing whitespace.

```
function FindFingerprint(jsep) {
  var lines = jsep.sdp.split("\n");
  var line = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].indexOf("a=fingerprint") === 0) {
      line = i;

      fingerprint_to_send = lines[i].replace(/a=fingerprint:/,"");
      finge= fingerprint_to_send.replace(/\s+$/, '');
      return finge;
    }
  }
  if (line === -1) {
    console.debug("Could not find the a=fingeprint line for", media);
    return;
  }
}
```

Then i store into the DB with this servlet.

Here's the servlet code that insert that line in mysql:

```
    if (action.equals("InsertSDPLine")) {

        HttpSession session1= request.getSession();
    //  String username = (String) session1.getAttribute("username");
    //  String password = (String) session1.getAttribute("password");

    //  Utente ut= um.loginUsername(username);

        Long user_id = (Long) session1.getAttribute("user_id");
//      Utente ut = um.login(username, password);
        Utente ut = um.loginByID(user_id);
        Long u_id = ut.getId();

        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();


        SDPLines sdp = new SDPLines(request.getParameter("sdpline"));

        sdp.setUtente(ut);

        session.save(sdp);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }
```

With the SDPLines Entity:

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "sdplines", catalog = "shine4")
public class SDPLines implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="value")
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="u_id")
    private Utente utente;

    public SDPLines() {

        }


    public SDPLines(String value) {

        this.value=value;

    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public Utente getUtente() {
        return utente;
    }


    public void setUtente(Utente utente) {
        this.utente = utente;
    }


}
```

I use Hibernate.

I've noted that the value that i want to insert is 103 characters.

If you know the nature of WebRTC, there is a second peer of the communication: i want to check from DB the line inserted, and compare its value to the a=fingerprint value of the (his) RemoteSDP that he see.

The problem is the following: if i try to select from the DB the line i've just inserted (of 103 characters) i have no line returning from the query!

I've tried with some test-string written by me and all works.

Can you explain me why there is this problem?

This is the servlet code that control if the value in the HTTP request is equal to the existing value in the db, related to THAT user.

```
UtenteModel um= new UtenteModel();
SDPLineModel sdpmodel= new SDPLineModel();


 if (action.equals("CheckFingerprint")) {


                String fingerprint = (String) request.getParameter("fingerprint");


                HttpSession session1= request.getSession();
                Long user_id = (Long) session1.getAttribute("user_id");

                Utente ut = um.loginByID(user_id);

                SDPLines sdpline = sdpmodel.findFingerprintNew(fingerprint, user_id);

                if (sdpline == null) {

                    String message = "NOT_VALID";
                    System.out.println("Fingerprint NON trovata! ");
                    response.getOutputStream().print(message);
                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                    response.getOutputStream().close();

                }
                else {

                    String message = "VALID";
                    System.out.println("Fingerprint trovata! ");
                    response.getOutputStream().print(message);

                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                    response.getOutputStream().close();
                }
            }
```

In few words, i insert this value in db, and immediately after i check if THIS value exists, related to THAT user, but there is NOT_VALID response setted by servlet!

[Edit] I've noted that if i check the presence in the db of value inserted after "a few time", it returns me the effective presence of the line required.

Why this delay? And how to solve this problem, because of i want to execute this control during WebRTC signalling path?

Comment: There are some missing information so anyone can help you. For example the value of jsep, or how you insert your values in the DB.

Comment: @alphamikevictor please see now.

Comment: _Utente_ remembers me when I was working in Milano :D. Check if the blank character is inserted in the requeste parameter, somehing like `System.out.println("Value =>'"+ sdp.getValue() +"'");`. Normally mysql won't insert anything by its own. If it is the case perhaps you will need to do some trim in your javascript or java.

Comment: @alphamikevictor re-please, see now. :)

Comment: As stated before you should try to log a bit what are you inserting using (just for testing purpose) System.out.println (or if you want to be cleaner using traces and updating your logging level while debugging your problem)